# Custom navigation icon not displayed // Jetpack Navigation

Tags: android, kotlin, navigation, android-jetpack

I'm trying to use a custom back navigation instead of using the default back arrow. I want to use a cancel icon:

[image]

by using `app:navigationIcon="@drawable/ic_cancel_white_24dp"` in my XML file.

When I run the app, however, the icon is never displayed. Instead, it shows the default back arrow in black:
[image]

I'm using the NAV controller and AppBarConfiguration to set up the toolbar (because the toolbar is styled differently for every fragment I have):

```
private fun setUpActionBar() {
   val navController = findNavController()
   val appBarConfiguration = AppBarConfiguration(navController.graph)
   binding.toolbar.setupWithNavController(navController, appBarConfiguration)
   binding.toolbar.inflateMenu(R.menu.menu)
}
```

How can I replace the default arrow with my custom icon? Also - why is the default arrow black? Is this a theming issue?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the `addOnDestinationChangedListener` to set your own icons after your setup method.

```
navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener { _, destination, _ ->
   if(destination.id == R.id.xxxx) {
       toolbar.setNavigationIcon(R.drawable.xxxx)
   } else {
       //
   }
}
```

About the color of the up icon check this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34581408/change-toolbar-back-arrow-color/34601647#34601647).
Just override the `colorOnPrimary` or the `colorControlNormal` in your `Toolbar` using the `android:theme` attribute.

Comment: Thanks this worked, I was struggling since a month to resolve this